# How to make Inside curve in container in Dart Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar

[image]
I making this this application in which I have to make a bottom navigation bar like this which is curved inside of the container so is there any perticular solution for this it will be appreciated. Thanks

I making this this application in which I have to make a bottom navigation bar like this which is curved inside of the container so is there any perticular solution for this it will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some great packages for something like this on pub.dev.
I would recommend you to always look for a package first in Flutter because there are a lot of them :)

[curved_bottom_navigation](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_bottom_navigation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I mentioned a just need a curve  in the center of the container not on icon presing or changing to another screen just want this curve in the center of the container which will not have any button or icon in it !

Comment: Jup, thats right. The intention of my Answer was that you should look on pub dev for packages wich fit your case. Because there a lot of them. Just search for "bottom bar" or "naviagtion bar" and you will find something