# How to make Inside curve in container in Dart Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar

I making this this application in which I have to make a bottom navigation bar like this which is curved inside of the container so is there any perticular solution for this it will be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

I making this this application in which I have to make a bottom navigation bar like this which is curved inside of the container so is there any perticular solution for this it will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Inside curve in container in Dart Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785009/how-to-make-inside-curve-in-container-in-dart-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution

```dart
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        height: 50,
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.green,
        notchMargin: 5,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        elevation: 5,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
          child: Row(
            // direction: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TextButton.icon(
                  label: Text(
                    "Home",
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
              const Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextButton.icon(
                  label: Text(
                    "Scan",
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.qr_code,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

here is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use BottomAppBar's shape property for something like this and then give it CircularNotchedRectangle shape to create a curve like that :

```
BottomAppBar(
          notchMargin: 7,
          color: Color(0xff1c1f26),
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle()
```

or just use a package like [stylish_bottom_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/stylish_bottom_bar)