# How to make Inside curve in container in Dart Flutter

Tags: css, flutter, dart, navigation, navigationbar

I making this this application in which I have to make a bottom navigation bar like this which is curved inside of the container so is there any perticular solution for this it will be appreciated. Thanksenter image description here

I making this this application in which I have to make a bottom navigation bar like this which is curved inside of the container so is there any perticular solution for this it will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Inside curve in container in Dart Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785009/how-to-make-inside-curve-in-container-in-dart-flutter)

Comment: Please share your bottom navigation bar UI

Comment: I'm afraid your question is making no sense to me (and simply repeating a paragraph rather than using the space to go into more detail is unhelpful). There is no image shown so 'like this' means nothing, and nor have you included the code of what you have tried so far or a description of what isn't working with it. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - we are very happy to help but we don't write code ab initio!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.